# Storing and Parsing Historical Data Using A Step Approach

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I've noticed two main concepts for storing and parsing historical data in a database.

1. Making a carbon Copy of the de-normalized data that coincides with a specific date
2. Keeping a version history for each table.

I'm wondering if it might work to keep an audit table of what was changed in order to get a query of what the data was at a given time:

For example you have a company with many employees. Throughout time employees come and go.

tbl_employee would have id and name

tble_employee_audit would have id, employee_id, hired_or_left, datetime

You would then have to take the current list of employees and step backwards through the audit table in order to get to a specific point in time. This would also take into account when someone leaves and then gets hired again.

This is a pretty simple example but with a more complex one do you think this will work? Would it be too taxing from processing standpoint?

Comment: Yes, this will work. In fact, this kind of feature has been done before. As to it being too taxing, it really depends on the size of the database itself and the computing resources you have available on hand, but for something like an employee database, which is not very big to begin with, it shouldn't be much of a problem at all.

Comment: Database experts have been wrestling with temporal data in the relational model for over a decade. There is no perfect solution. Richard Snodgrass has an excellent book (somewhat dated and now out of print), but available as a pdf (I believe). Martin Fowler's short paper "Temporal Patterns" (also dated) gives a very concise overview of some approaches to handling the dimension of "time" in a relational database.